# Fedora 25 - VLC preferences - cut off

Tags: fedora, vlc-media-player

Fedora 25 and vlc. The values are cut off in the (all) preferences - Everything is fine in the (simple) settings

[image]

Comment: And what is the question? You probably wanted to send a bug report to the developers/packagers, isn't it?

Comment: Really, the question is, how do I fix this? I apologize if this isn't obvious. If the settings aren't readable, I can't adjust them.